# Input from Serial (FTDI) to a php/python script

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, serial-port, arduino

I and some other people are working on a project that includes using an Arduino with an Ubuntu Server (running Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit). Currently we have the device connected and we can see the Arduino putting data in /dev/ttyUSB0. I can successfully cat it to another file.

We have a MySQL database that this information will be translated to, via either a python or php script. I need to know how to get the input from the serial port to be the input for that script. The device will be responding at least 20 times a second. The script essentially just needs to take whatever response it gets and insert the corresponding row to the MySQL database.

Has anyone done this before who could help out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing just fine. You could directly open `/dev/ttyUSB0` like a file in your code, but as write and read access should be done at a certain pace (serial baudrate, ...), it may be problematic (but still possible: I never tried it, but you can [configure the TTY](http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/LinuxTTY) to directly write in it).

The missing link is you have to access `/dev/ttyUSB0` like a serial port.

You mentionned Python: with it you can use [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/). It also makes your code more portable toward other operating systems.
A quick `apt-get install python-serial` or `apt-get install python3-serial` should work.

You have some examples in the [Arduino playground](http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Python):

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
while 1:
    ser.readline()
```

There are plenty others in the [PySerial introduction](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html).

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it and let you know what we figure out this week! :)

Comment: It wasn't even as hard as that. I wrote it in php and just used the fopen and a while loop with fgets...worked like a charm!

Comment: Unless you configure the TTY, I think you may have problems with that method if you write in it. But if you just read in it and it works as you like, fine. The main issue is that this way is not portable with other operating systems like Windows, but I guess you do not care :-)